# RSpec kind_of? returns wrong result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am on the quest to learn RSpec. Currently I am studying the [built-in matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers).

I am a little confused on `expect(actual).to be_kind_of(expected)`

On [relishapp site](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/built-in-matchers/specify-types-of-objects), it says the behavior of `be_kind_of` to be

> obj.should be_kind_of(type): calls obj.kind_of?(type), which returns true if type is in obj's class hierarchy or is a module and is included in a class in obj's class hierarchy.

APIdock states [this example](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/kind_of%3F):

```
module M;    end
class A
  include M
end
class B < A; end
class C < B; end

b.kind_of? A       #=> true
b.kind_of? B       #=> true
b.kind_of? C       #=> false
b.kind_of? M       #=> true
```

However, when I tested it on RSpec, it returns false when I do:

```
module M;    end
class A
  include M
end
class B < A; end
class C < B; end

describe "RSpec expectation" do
  context "comparisons" do
    let(:b) {B.new}

    it "test types/classes/response" do
      expect(b).to be kind_of?(A)
      expect(b).to_not be_instance_of(A)
    end
  end
end


1) RSpec expectation comparisons test types/classes/response
     Failure/Error: expect(b).to be kind_of?(A)

       expected false
            got #<B:70361555406320> => #<B:0x007ffca7081be0>
```

Why does my RSpec return false when the example says it ought to return `true`?

Answer (score 5):

You're writing

```
expect(b).to be kind_of?(A)
```

but the the matcher is

```
expect(b).to be_kind_of(A)
```

Note the underscores and the lack of a question mark.
The test you wrote will pass if

```
b.equal?(kind_of?(A))
```

You're calling `#kind_of?` on the Rspec test itself not `b` as you would be with the matcher.

Comment: You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

You're mix a two kind of matchers, [`should` and `expect`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md#why-switch-over-from-should-to-expect). Check the documentation for [rspec-expectations](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#typesclasses):

```
expect(actual).to be_an_instance_of(expected) # passes if actual.class == expected
expect(actual).to be_a(expected)              # passes if actual.kind_of?(expected)
expect(actual).to be_an(expected)             # an alias for be_a
expect(actual).to be_a_kind_of(expected)      # another alias
```

You should choose [use both](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md#using-either-expect-or-should-or-both), or one of them.